# Pull Always Leads to Conflicts. (GIT)

Tags: git, egit, git-pull

Why is it that every time I do a pull, well maybe not every time, 90% of the time, I do a pull, I get a conflict? Do I have to commit my local changes first before doing a pull? But even that occasionally leads to a conflict. What is the right sequence of checking out and checking in code?

I am using EGit by the way.

5 months in, and I am still not sold on the idea of Git! I feel its over-engineered for something that is just used to store lines of code.

Comment: try with `git pull --rebase`

Comment: Do I have to do it all the time?

Comment: Conflicts rise when the code you are pulling from the remote touches the same lines that you have modified yourself. Perhaps there's something you could improve in your workflow so that this wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git pull --rebase`.. its sync server change by doing`(fetch & merge)`... its recommended to use instead of `git pull`..

Look [this](https://gitolite.com/git-pull--rebase) for details.